# How to specify relationships between tables in ZF2 using ZFcBase

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i'm new in Zend Framework. I'm working with an application that uses the following db pattern: **Controler -> Service -> Mapper**.
And i have an **entity** for each table and a **hydrator** file. What i need is to join tables in SQL query, but i don´t know how to access the results from the joined table, cause it only feeds the entity of the current table. Here´s my code:

Controller:

```
$userEntity = new \Portal\Entity\Iamuserdb();
$userEntity->setIamUserDbId($this->params('id'));
$service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Portal\Service\Reports');
$user = $service->getUserById($userEntity)
```

Service (Reports):

```
protected $iamuserMapper;

public function selectUsers(){
$usuarios = $this->getIamUserMapper()->fetchAllUsers();
return $usuarios;
}

protected function getIamUserMapper()
{
if ($this->iamuserMapper == null) {
$this->iamuserMapper = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Portal\Mapper\Iamuser');
}
return $this->iamuserMapper;
}
```

Mapper (Iamuser):

```
public function fetchAllUsers()
{
$select = $this->getSelect();
$select->from('IAMUser')
->join('IAMUser_IAMGroup', 'IAMUser.iamUserDbId=IAMUser_IAMGroup.IAMUser_iamUserDbId', array('IAMUser_iamUserDbId', 'iamGroups_iamGroupDbId'), 'left')
->join('IAMGroup', 'IAMGroup.iamGroupDbId=IAMUser_IAMGroup.iamGroups_iamGroupDbId', array(), 'left');
return $this->select($select);
}
```

Hydrator:

```
class Iamuser extends Hydrator
{
protected function getEntity()
{
return 'Portal\Entity\Iamuserdb';
}

protected function getMap()
{
return array(
);
}
}
```

In my Module.php from the module i have the factory:

```
'factories' => array(
'Portal\Mapper\Iamuser' => function($sm) {
$dbAdapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($sm->get('Configuration')['db']);
$mapper = new Mapper\Iamuser();
$mapper->setEntityPrototype(new Entity\Iamuserdb())
->setHydrator(new Mapper\Hydrator\Iamuser())
->setDbSlaveAdapter($dbAdapter)
->setDbAdapter($dbAdapter);
return $mapper;
},
}
```

See in my mapper i'm joining two tables, but how to fetch these results, since they came from another table and is not feed in Entity class? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve my problem. All i have to do is return this statement:

```
return $this->select($select)->getDataSource();
```

So i skip the hydration results in entities and get raw PDO array, this way i can join tables.